# How do I simultaneously scrape two pages and produce two distinct lists within one nested 'for-loop'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping from two URLs that have the same DOM structure, and so I'm trying to find a way to scrape both of them at the same time.
The only caveat is that the data scraped from both these pages need to end up on distinctly named lists.

To explain with example, here is what I've tried:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


urls = ['https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_career.html',
       'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_per_48_career.html',]

ws_list = []
ws48_list = []

categories = [ws_list, ws48_list]

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    section = soup.find('table', class_='stats_table')
    for a in section.find_all('a'):
        player_name = a.text
        for cat_list in categories:
            cat_list.append(player_name)
print(ws48_list)
print(ws_list)
```

This ends up printing two identical lists when I was shooting for 2 lists unique to its page.
How do I accomplish this? Would it be better practice to code it another way?

Comment: You are adding the same item `player_name` for both lists.

Comment: Please find my updated comment. I was missing a certain part.

Comment: @offeltoffel How would I make a distinction between the two pages every iteration?

Comment: I was about to give you a solution with `enumerate`, but the user Uvar was quicker. `enumerate` allows you to iterate over items and count their number at the same time. You address the item via `url` and assign it to an index of your categories with `i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to append to already existing lists. Just create new ones. Make a function to do the scrape and pass each url in turn to it.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ['https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_career.html',
       'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_per_48_career.html',]

def parse_page(url, headers={}):

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    section = soup.find('table', class_='stats_table')
    return [a.text for a in section.find_all('a')]


ws_list, ws48_list = [parse_page(url) for url in urls]

print('ws_list = %r' % ws_list)
print('ws8_list = %r' % ws48_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add them to the appropriate list and the problem is solved?

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    section = soup.find('table', class_='stats_table')
    for a in section.find_all('a'):
        player_name = a.text
        categories[i].append(player_name)
print(ws48_list)
print(ws_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to define your scraping logic, then just call it for your urls.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def scrape(url):    
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    section = soup.find('table', class_='stats_table')
    names = []
    for a in section.find_all('a'):
        player_name = a.text
        names.append(player_name)
    return names    

ws_list = scrape('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_career.html')
ws48_list = scrape('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/ws_per_48_career.html')

print(ws_list)
print(ws48_list)
```